# How to display main page and not the other random page that opens up as popups in webview?

Tags: android, webview

For example I have a website that plays video Say A and 2 say B and C other webpages that popsup when I click play video on A. I dont want B or C to be displayed on the main page I want only the main page A to be showing up on the screen in WebView in Android.